# Understanding sys.dm_exec_sessions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Couple of questions on `dm_exec_sessions`. When I run the query

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

it shows me among other columns a `status` and a `transaction_isolation_level` column.

It is my understanding that `sys.dm_exec_sessions` returns a row per authenticated session. In my understanding several queries/transactions can be run using this session.

1. What is the meaning of `transaction_isolation_level` that is returned per session? Is it the isolation level of the last transaction that was run on the database using that connection?
2. There are some (a couple) sessions that have a status of sleeping. What does that mean? Should we be worried about this? Are these transactions from the web server that have failed to rollback?

Comment: This belongs on Database Administrators SE. Flagged for migration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my understanding several queries/transactions can be run using this
> session.

This is incorrect. You will always be able to execute at most one query and have at most one user active transaction in a session, never more than one of either.

A *connection* can have multiple *sessions*, but that is a different story. [sys.dm_exec_connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx)

If you discover SERIALIZABLE sessions and you wonder why, then remember that [using new TransactionScope() Is Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful)

Comment: Yes. We do have some serializable transactions but most of them are read committed. Thanks for clarifying connections vs sessions. If every query *creates a session* then do the sessions that have a status of 'sleeping' imply that a query has been issued and the session is still waiting for the results?

Comment: Is not true that every query creates a session either. A session is created when a connection logs in. A session will run many requests, one after another, [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) and a request consists of statements, some of the statements being queries. A session that is sleeping it means it has no current request. Consider your client code, when you open a connection and you issue a command, followed by another one. Between the two command the connection's session is idle, ie. *sleeping*.

Comment: Got it. If there are many sleeping connections that last sometimes for a couple of days with the same sessionid it means that the open connections are not properly closed?

Comment: SQL Server itself has a few internal sessions and you have to consider that. `sys.dm_exec_sessions` can be correlated with `sys.dm_exec_connections` and the later contains client IP. Long idle connections *may* indicate a leaked connection in client code, but you have to consider that most clients (eg. ADO.Net) use connection pooling by default.

Answer (score 1):

The session itself has a transaction_isolation_level.  And batch/request running in that session will use that  transaction_isolation_level unless it explicitly changes it.

A status of Sleeping just means that the session is idle and not currently running a batch/request.  (I.E., it's waiting for it's client connection to send it a command to execute).  It's not normally anything to worry about.

The official doc for sys.dm_exec_sessions is here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I see in the results that our webserver makes two connections one with isolation_level serializable (4) and another with Read committed (2). It is the same Why is that? Should it not consistently use either 4 or 2?

Comment: That's up to whoever wrote the code for your Webserver.  Connections and Sessions can set or change this as they wish.